# Django: Creating a model instance when duplicate model names exist

Tags: django, django-models

In one of my views I am importing models from two apps:

```
from mysite.business.models import Location
from mysite.directory.models import Location
```

As you can see, both Models have the same name. If I want to create an instance of one of these models, how do I define which one I require?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give them different names.

```
from mysite.business.models import Location as BusinessLocation
from mysite.directory.models import Location as DirectoryLocation
```

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. I was considering this approach but hadn't found it anywhere in the Django docs. Is this the recommended way of handling the same situation when using 3rd party apps?

Comment: It's the standard way of handling import conflicts in Python.